# Is Tooltip broken in MMA 11.1.1?

Tags: plotting, bugs, tooltip

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0 and persisting through 11.2.0**

---

I have just discovered that `Tooltip` works differently from as described in the documentation, at least in my version of MMA (11.1.1.0, Windows x64). Below are two screenshots from `Tooltip` documentation page, the first one was obtained before evaluation (tooltips are correct, labelling every curve) and the second one after the cell evaluation --  tooltip shows now its full argument. Is it a bug?

[image: Correct tooltip]

[image: Wrong tooltip]

Comment: I'm seeing this with 11.1.1, too, on macOS. Looks like a bug to me. I see same thing with `Plot[{Tooltip[Sin[x]], Tooltip[Cos[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}]`. And same issue in the example under *Applications* on the `Tooltip` doc page that uses `Plot3D`.

Comment: I don't see this in version 10.4; can somebody with version 11.0 check, please?

Comment: @J.M. - works correctly with v11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks @Bob; I've edited the bug header. Please feel free to do so the next time if you have version-relevant information.

Comment: just checked in 11.2, the bug is still there.

Comment: Bug has been reported to Wolfram.

Comment: It is fixed in 11.3

Comment: @OlegSoloviev a different part of the page is now broken in 12.0, the one for polynomial factorizations, first of the applications section of the reference page.